# jquery validate array inputs error

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, jquery-validate

I have a form that has multiple inputs array, but I just want some that are mandatory, which you want to apply the class ignoring ignore. the problem is that jquery validate check all mandatory. How could I avoid this:

a simple example:

html

```
<form id='register' name='register' method='post' action='' >   
enter code herearray1: <input type='text' name='name[]' id='name'/>
   input type 1: <input type='text' name='name[]' id='name'/>
   input type 1: <input type='text' class="noValidate" name='name[]' id='name'/>
   input type 1: <input type='text' name='name[]' id='name'/>

   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
```

function that validate the form

```
function ValidateFormNewContract()
{
    $('#formAltaContrac').submit(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#formAltaContrac').validate().settings.ignore = []; 
    });

    $('#formAltaContrac').validate(
    {
        ignore: ".noValidate",
        invalidHandler: function(e,validator) 
        {
            if(validator.errorList.length > 0)
            {
                var id = $(validator.errorList[0].element).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()[0].id;
                $('a[href=#'+id+']').click();
                $(validator.errorList[0].element).focus();
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
//            alert('enviado');
            SendNewContractData();
        },
        rules: {
            'name[]':{required: true},
//            
        }
    });
}
```

note: I have modified jquery validate to perform validations array inputs,

validations array inputs makes them well, but do not get to ignore the class

and another question, how could I do to make the span Feeding Fail jquery to validate an input spread to other inputs to array fault?

Comment: You can't use the same `name` more than once.  jQuery Validate plugin uses the `name` to keep track of inputs so it must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
enter code herearray1: <input type='text' name='name[]' id='name'/>
input type 1: <input type='text' name='name[]' id='name'/>
input type 1: <input type='text' class="noValidate" name='name[]' id='name'/>
input type 1: <input type='text' name='name[]' id='name'/>
```

1)  The biggest problem is that all of your input elements contain the same `name="name[]"`.  Poor semantics aside, you cannot duplicate the `name` attribute since the plugin uses it to keep track of the input elements.

2)  As far as "ignoring" inputs, if you don't specify a `rule` for an input, then the input will not be evaluated.  Simple enough, and once you fix the naming issues above, this part will take care of itself.